# Could not load database configuration. No such file - database.yml - OpsWorks

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, aws-opsworks

I'm deploying for first time my application using OpsWorks (Ubuntu 14.04) and when the migration is running I'm getting this error:

Could not load database configuration. No such file - /srv/www/todoapp/releases/20150122121517/config/database.yml

I don't understand this error because I have a /config/database.yml in my rails application and is being pushed to bitbucket correctly.

You can see here my .gitignore file:

```
# If you find yourself ignoring temporary files generated by your text editor
# or operating system, you probably want to add a global ignore instead:
#   git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore_global'

# Ignore bundler config.
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*.log
/tmp
```

Comment: Are you using an Amazon RDS database?

Comment: No, I'm just using a rails instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Amazon Opsworks will override your `database.yml` file. You will have to add custom JSON to configure your production database.

Anyway, here is what your JSON should look like.

```
{
  "deploy": {
    "app_short_name": {  # this should be the short name Opsworks has given your app.
      "database": {
        "adapter": "postgresql", # change if you are using mysql
        "encoding": "unicode",
        "host": "your-host",
        "port": "5432", # change if you are using mysql
        "database": "your_database_name",
        "pool": "10",
        "username": "your_database_username",
        "password": "your_database_password"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can add this in the Opsworks Stack Settings.

- Log into your Opsworks
- Click `Stack` on your left sidebar.
- Click `Stack settings` button.
- Towards the bottom you will see **Configuration management** section. You can add your custom JSON there to configure your database properly.

The above settings are for a Postgres database configuration. You will probably need to change it up a bit using mysql..

I have this set up using an Amazon RDS postgres database. RDS also supports mysql.

Hope this helps get you one step closer to deploying your app. Good luck.

Comment: Where I can find the host, port, database_name, username and password? I only created the rails instance because opsworks is using mysql by default then I don't know where I can find all this attributes. Also my custom json looks like this right now:
{
"deploy":
{
"ariadna":
{
"database":
{
"adapter": "mysql2"
}
}
}
}

Comment: Do you prefer to use Postgres over mysql?

Comment: No I prefer use mysql

Comment: Alright, well I would recommend using an [Amazon RDS instance](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/) for your database. If not, you will have to create a database on your server and set it up with a name, username/password, etc..Just like you do locally essentially.

Comment: I have a Rails app which does **not** have/use a database. Is it impossible to deploy a Rails app without a database connection? I keep giving dummy/sqlite3 connection info in my JSON, but AWS apparently doesn't like it/doesn't use it to make a `database.yml` file, and then Apache2 complains it couldn't read `config/database.yml`. Any ideas?

Comment: @mmcrae, Good question. You can definitely deploy without a database, however I'm not sure how Opsworks likes this unfortunately. Have you removed `require 'active_record/railtie'` from your `config/application.rb`?

Comment: @JustinLicata good suggestion, I may try that another time. For now, I got it to work with dummy `mysql2` JSON data (and making sure `gem mysql2` was in my `Gemfile`.) Now I have another newbie confusion: I go to the internal IP address of the OpsWorks instance and I get a `404 Not Found` page (not one supplied by the Rails app)

Comment: in my case, google cloud platform returns the same error while DEPLOYMENT `Cannot load 'Rails.application.database_configuration' Could not load database configuration. No such file -` as probably it can't find the file database.yml file

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using an RDS instance, make sure to:

- Create an RDS layer (Layers>>Add layer, RDS)
- Register the instance with your app (Apps>>Edit, data sources)